# Cant send object to database JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa

Im trying to send my customer with name and adress to my database, but it doesnt seem to wanna work. The program works but it doesnt enter anything into my database.

My database looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE PIZZA.CUSTOMER(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ADRESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
```

Here i send my name and adress into the customer object

```
private void sendOrder(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("thanku.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String adress = request.getParameter("adress");
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
    Customer customer = new Customer(adress,name);
    dbHandler.storeInTable(customer);
}
```

And here i try to send it to the database, but it doesnt work

```
public class DBHandler {

private final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Customer";
public boolean storeInTable(Customer customer) {
    boolean result = false;
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(customer);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        result = true;
    } finally {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the jpa entity class Customer

```
  @Entity
  @Table(schema = "PIZZA", name="CUSTOMER")
  @NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
  public class Customer implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String adress;

private String name;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(String adress,String name) {
    this.adress = adress;
    this.name = name;

}
```

[image: Here is my persistence.xml file]

This is the JPA provider log

```
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-09 17:30:28.993--ServerSession(24639535)--                   **Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class model.Customer] is set to [FIELD]. 
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-09 17:30:29.023--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class model.Customer] is being defaulted to: Customer.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-09 17:30:29.047--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--The column name for element [name] is being defaulted to: NAME.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-09 17:30:29.048--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--The column name for element [adress] is being defaulted to: ADRESS.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2015-12-09 17:30:29.048--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--The column name for element [id] is being defaulted to: ID.
[EL Info]: 2015-12-09 17:30:29.688--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Fine]: connection: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.13--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.JavaDBPlatform
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.145--ServerSession(24639535)--Connection(4727047)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
platform=>JavaDBPlatform
user name=> "PIZZA"
datasource URL=> "jdbc:derby:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/db/MyDBgrp2;create=true"
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.147--ServerSession(24639535)--  Connection(180962)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:derby:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/db/MyDBgrp2
User: PIZZA
Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver  Version: 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.267--ServerSession(24639535)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--file:/C:/Users/isac/workspace mars/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/OnlinePizza/WEB-INF/classes/_Customer login successful
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.577--ServerSession(24639535)--Connection(180962)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--SELECT * FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = SEQ_GEN
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.636--ClientSession(28727725)--Connection(180962)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [50, SEQ_GEN]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.674--ClientSession(28727725)--Connection(180962)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
bind => [SEQ_GEN]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-12-09 17:30:30.687--ClientSession(28727725)--Connection(180962)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-10,5,main])--INSERT INTO PIZZA.CUSTOMER (ID, ADRESS, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [601, asd, sdf]**
```

Comment: what kind of error you get?

Comment: please elaborate what does "doesn't work" mean here? no error, but the data is not persisted or you get some stacktrace in the log files?

Comment: @zacheusz i dont get any kind of error, The program works but i dont get my customer in my database. no error but the data is not persisted

Comment: and when you look at the log what do you see? aka debugging

Comment: @NeilStockton the only messages that displays is [EL Info]: connection: 2015-12-09 17:09:18.344--ServerSession(27029665)--file:/C:/Users/isac/workspace mars/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/OnlinePizza/WEB-INF/classes/_Customer login successful

Comment: @NeilStockton ive edited the thread with the JPA provider log

Comment: From the above log we can see that data were inserted (2015-12-09 17:30:30.687). Are you looking for inserted data just after commit (debug session in Eclipse with a breakpoint at line `result = true;`) or after program exit ?

Answer (score 0):

for me it seems like you always rollback the data you just wrote into the database in your finally block

```
finally {
    if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) //is always active
        em.getTransaction().rollback(); //so it always rolls back
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: No, the additional isActive() check prevents that. Only when the transaction is not committed will the rollback happen.

Answer (score 0):

From the log provided, I can see that the insertion happened but seems not committed. So, in your persistence.xml add the below property

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/> and add this attribute to persistence-unit tag: transaction-type='RESOURCE_LOCAL'
```

Eclipselink needs to know which database it's communicating with to assure correct transaction management.

Comment: Out of interest : WHY does EclipseLink need to know what database its communicating with ??? The JDBC driver tells it! Other JPA implementations don't need it. FWIW The OP presents no evidence that it is not committed.

Comment: DB detection happens automatically by the provider using connection metadata. The property is just to guarantee the correct selection of DB type. The OP shows the insertion, but no commit appears in the log. Eclipselink prints commit if  happened. There are no exceptions were thrown too

Comment: @hragheb i tried adding this but it didint do the trick. So right now my issue is with the database cause i made a query out of the database and i found that all of my customers has been stored inside there. But i cant find my database anywhere. So i know its working but cant seem to find it.